# Did animals help Prophet Ibrahim (PBUH) while he was in fire?

Tags: history, prophet-ibrahim

According to this reference,Tafsir Qomi.volume2.page72-73,When Prophet Ibrahim (PBUH) was thrown to the fire,animals asked Allah to help Ibrahim but Allah just allowed frog to help him.frog brought water to fire off and Two-thirds of frog Was burned.

Is it right? Is there any other references about it?

Answer (score 1):

I never heard of this mentioned anywhere in Quran (or also its tasfir) explains very clearly.

> Verse (21:69) - English Translation
>
> Allah said, "O fire, be coolness and safety upon Abraham."

Indeed Allah (swt) created the fire and he ascribe to it (the fire) the ability to cause harm (to burn). And it is easy for Allah (swt) to change these attributes since he (Allah) has power over all things.

Answer (score -4):

I am not saying that that is not what happened... But his Tafsir must be backed by narrations.

In Shia view:

Mufadhal ibn-Omar said: I was sitting by Imam Sadiq and he said:
Do you know where did Yousef cloth come from?
I said: I don't know, please tell me.
Imam said: As they wanted to throw prophet Ibrahim into the fire, **Gabriel descended and gave him a heavenly cloth** and he put it on and the fire [became cold and lost](http://quran.com/21/69) its affect on him and at the last day of his life he gave it to Ishaq (PBUH) and and he later gave it to Jacob (PBUH) and when Joseph was born, his father gave him the cloth...until the day that he sent that same [cloth back to his father by his brothers and he was able to see again](http://quran.com/12/93) and this was that same heavenly cloth.
I said: where is this cloth now?
Imam said: It's with to who it belongs (meaning its with me as I got it from my father and will give to my son) to and eventually it will be given the Qa'im of al-Muhammad.And when he appears, he would put on that cloth and all the people on the world, east and west would sense its redolent.

Kamal al-Din Pg.327